# How do I Know if I have left scope of document/browser

Tags: javascript, windows, dom, browser

I am clicking on input type file, this will open a popup of operating system directory(windows) where I can select some file to upload. 
Is there any method/event to know if I have left the scope of browser/window/doc when I am moving cursor pointer to os directory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>(console.log('mouse outside')))` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work for this specific case.

Comment: I doubt there is anything and not sure why you would need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky -- the window [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event is definitely triggered when the file picker dialog takes focus, but this event will also be triggered for every other window deactivation which is not desirable.

To get around that, you could register an event listener for the window blur only when the file input is activated by the keyboard or mouse, and then remove the event listener when the window regains focus.

```js
function handleFilePickerActivation(event) {
  window.onblur = function () {
    console.log("Focus left the browser in the file picker dialog");
  };
}

window.onfocus = function () {
  this.onblur = null;
};

// The dialog can be entered via mouseclick
fileInput.addEventListener("click", handleFilePickerActivation);

// The dialog can be entered via keyboard (spacebar, enter, etc.)
fileInput.addEventListener("keypress", handleFilePickerActivation);
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file">
```